# npgsql, arrays and C# the operator does not exist: text[] = text

Tags: c#, arrays, npgsql

. I would really appreciate if somebody could help me out to fix this problem

I'm developing an application using npgsql and c# and when i want to retrieve some information from a table which contains a column with an array of elements, the problem starts when I want to use a query like this:

```
   NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from book_editions", conn);
```

the compiler shows the column which contains the elements example({1st,2nd,3d}) as "Data.System.String[] therefore i tried to fix the problem by using parameters....
like is shown here below.

```
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=postgres; " +"Password=admin;Database=library_system;");
    conn.Open();

    //////string[] options = new string[] { "marketing", "m" }; already tried and failed

    ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
        l.Add("2th");
        l.Add("3th");

        NpgsqlParameter p = new NpgsqlParameter("parameterlist", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text);

        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from book_editions where editions = any (:parameterlist)", conn);

        //editions is the column which has the array of elements, its datatype is text

        p.Value = l.ToArray();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

     NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     while (dr.Read())

     Console.Write("{0} \n", dr[0].ToString());

     Console.ReadKey();

      conn.Close();
```

when i execute the code the `cmd.ExecuteReader` throws this error:

```
npgsql was unhandled
ERROR: 42883: el operador no existe: text[] = text
```

i got the following sentence as a tip....

> Ningún operador coincide con el nombre y el tipo de los argumentos.
>   Puede ser necesario agregar conversiones explícitas de tipos. (there
>   is no operator which matches with the name and argument types, it
>   would be required to add explicit type castings

does anybody know the solution? :( :( i already tried hard.

Comment: Have you tried to use List<T>?

Comment: no yet i would appreciate if could give me an example, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

```
   var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select array_to_string(column, ', '),othercolumn,othercolumn from table",connection);

   var l = new ArrayList();
   l.Add("2th");
   l.Add("3th");

   cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("parameterlist", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));      

   cmd.Parameters[0].Value = l.ToArray();

   var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   while (dr.Read())
     Console.Write("{0} \n", dr[0].ToString());

   Console.ReadKey();
   conn.Close();
```

Try again!

Comment: thank you very much! im trying your solution now , and the compiler is throwing now the following error: ERROR: 42704: no se pudo encontrar un tipo de array para el tipo de dato text[](""" it was not possible to find an array type for the datatype text[])

Comment: Ok, try it (attempt for: 'NpgsqlDbType.VarChar', i'm not sure about that, use your intelisense, change the cmd.parameters.... line for:

cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameterlist", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.VarChar).Value = l; I will edit my post

Comment: thank you very much again for your time :) , unfortunately it shows me the same error as before but now with the datatype varchar ERROR: 42883: the operator does not exist: text[] = character varying

Comment: oh i changed that :) because the compiler threw the syntax error :(

Comment: any other suggestions? :( :(

Comment: yep i tried now but if i remove the @" the parameter is not recognizing , it throws an error saying that the column parameterlist does not exist , i really don't know from where start to now, i really really appreciate your help, unfortunately i still have not found the error

Comment: now im trying by using the following syntax //var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM || administration( $1 ) || .departments WHERE departments = ANY(' ||  $2  || ') ", conn);

Comment: Did effect? Try using another type of data, such INT.
Start with one parameter, once it's ok you try with array and so on..

Comment: i didnt work as well,im gonna try by changing the datatype as you suggested , thanks!

Comment: I FIXED IT!!!!!! :D   this is the syntax!!!... NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select array_to_string(column, ', '),othercolumn,othercolumn from table",connection); THANKS FOR ALL YOUR HELP Felipe! obrigado! :)

Comment: Nice to know you got it working! Unfortunately Npgsql doens't have direct support for this type of query. ("in (parameterlist)") :( Net data provider doesn't have an API for this type of query. I think we could create some util methods which would help users get this type of query working. I'll add your solution to our documentation about this type of query. Thank you for sharing your solution. :)

Comment: IIRC, it should work if you had a function on the server that took array parameters, and the function did the `in`.

Comment: my pleasure Francisco, im so glad to give a small contribution, it really took days for me to fix this, i hope somebody could find this solution in order to save time searching , thank you very much for your help. ,  and Jon Hanna Im gonna check your suggestion thanks a lot as well to you :)

Comment: @Andonirock I've update my answer above to help others on this. May you want to check it as the valid answer or create another one with your solution. Thx